# Close Twitter Bootbox after x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

Is it possible to close a twitter bootbox after 10 seconds?! i open it like this:

```
bootbox.confirm("{{$steps[0]}}","accept","decline" ,function(result) {
    if (result) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This code will close the open bootbox automatically after 10 seconds.

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    bootbox.hideAll();
}, 10000); // 10 seconds expressed in milliseconds
```

See the [documentation here](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html)

Comment: Wow, that is working perfect! Another Question, can i show the seconds remaining in the bootbox?!

Comment: @chrizstone Glad it helped. You would need to post that as another question, it's slightly more involved. If this has answered the original question don't forget to select it as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I just committed a patch that would add this functionality to bootbox.

It is available on the link below.

https://github.com/bhagyas/bootbox/commit/72cd1ada43d3aa74f0dcfb10d66219fe208063af

After adding this patch to your bootbox.js, you could set an additional timeOut option in your options for bootbox.

```
bootbox.dialog({
    message  : "Your operation completed successfully.",
    timeOut : 2000
});
```

Cheers.